# Ionic 3 Google Map does not display on Android + IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I use Ionic 3 version and I try to add a page into my app, to display a map with markers.
I already use for my app a Google Map Id for Autocomplete (Google places...). 
I went to Google APIs and I added Map Embed, Javascript etc... to my API Key.
But The page appears with "Google" in the bottom and the display button", but the map is empty.
See attached file...

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

$ ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="AIzaSyB6mEnxH4vC+++++++++9wnXXNNmK2co" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="AIzaSyB6mEnxH4v++++++++++++++wnXXNNmK2co"
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-maps

**Home.ts:**

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMaps, CameraPosition, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMap, MarkerOptions, Marker } from "@ionic-native/google-maps";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private googleMaps: GoogleMaps) {

  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.loadMap();
}

loadMap() {
 // make sure to create following structure in your view.html file
 // and add a height (for example 100%) to it, else the map won't be visible
 // <ion-content>
 //  <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
 // </ion-content>

 // create a new map by passing HTMLElement
 let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

 let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);

 // listen to MAP_READY event
 // You must wait for this event to fire before adding something to the map or modifying it in anyway
 map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(
   () => {
     console.log('Map is ready!');
     // Now you can add elements to the map like the marker
   }
 );

 // create CameraPosition
 let position: CameraPosition = {
   target: {
     lat: 43.0741904,
     lng: -89.3809802
   },
   zoom: 18,
   tilt: 30
 };

 // move the map's camera to position
} 
}
```

Home.HTML

```html
Home.html :
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Map
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="addMarker()"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>Add Marker</button>
    </ion-buttons>  
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
 
<ion-content>
<div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div> 
</ion-content>
```

Home.scss

```css
page-home {

}
```

Comment: add related HTML and CSS if any.

Comment: I edited my aks with html and css added.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `ngAfterViewInit`. 
You must wait `platform.ready()`

```
// Wait the native plugin is ready.
platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.loadMap();
});
```

Full code is https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.0.0/ionic-native/README.md

Repo: https://github.com/mapsplugin/ionic-google-maps

---

The current official document page is wrong. I sent a pull request, but it's waiting now.
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/pull/1834

Comment: Hi, I tried with your issue but still map doesnt appear.

Comment: After this, I followed the documentation of the link you sent and I still have no map appearing. I guess my problem comes from my API. Could you please indicate me how to configure the API to work for Google Autocomplete + making appear the Map.

Comment: I found a bug in the latest code. Please try to reinstall the plugin or specify the camera option to the second argument. https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.0.0/class/Map/getMap/README.md#create-a-map-with-initialize-options

Comment: The bug was fixed in the @ionic-native/core and @ionic-native/google-maps ver4.2.0

Please reinstall these two packages.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/core
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/google-maps

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code and make sure you are using correct API key, write following code in your .ts file:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
   }
   loadMap() {

        let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
          camera: {
            target: {
              lat: 43.0741904,
              lng: -89.3809802
            },
            zoom: 18,
            tilt: 30
          }
        };

        this.map = this.googleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

        // Wait the MAP_READY before using any methods.
        this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Map is ready!');

            this.map.addMarker({
                title: 'Ionic',
                icon: 'blue',
                animation: 'DROP',
                position: {
                  lat: 43.0741904,
                  lng: -89.3809802
                }
              })
              .then(marker => {
                marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
                  .subscribe(() => {
                    alert('clicked');
                  });
              });

          });
      }
```

In your .html file define map like below

```
<ion-content>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 100%;"></div>
</ion-content>
```